# How to focus a div block on click of button using Angular with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a button and another div with some content. I want to set focus to the div when user clicks on the button. I know in javascript i can do it by document.getElementById("divID").focus();But is there any way in typescript.

Comment: The premise of this question is wrong. The TypeScript way is the JavaScript way by definition.

Comment: @AluanHaddad The premise is changed. He used angular tag obvisously it was for angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('selector') selector: ELementRef;

focus() {
    this.selector.nativeElement.focus()
}
```

in html

```
   <button (click)='focus()'> focus</button>
```

and the 2 approach will be

```
 <sole-element #el> <sole-element>
<button (click)='focus(el)'> focus</button>
or
<button (click)='el.focus()'> focus</button>
```

and in ts file

```
 focus(el) {
    el.nativeElement.focus()
}
```

Comment: The premise of this question is wrong. The TypeScript way is the JavaScript way by definition. Therefore this answer does not apply to the question which asks how to do it in TypeScript not how to do it in Angular

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**in html file :**

```
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primay" (click)="onFocus()">onFocus</button>
</div>
<div>
        <input type="text" name="name" #focusContent>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('focusContent') el: any;

    onFocus() {
        this.el.nativeElement.focus();
    }
}
```